# In this phrase, should I use "cheered" or "were cheering"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, simple-past

I came across this phrase answering exercises about the difference between past continuous, past simple, and past perfect.

**"The crowd _____ (cheer) when the referee _____ (blow) the final whistle."**

If I am not mistaken, in the last blank it should be "blew", regardless of the first verb.

So which sounds more suitable: "cheered" or "were cheering"?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Either one is acceptable, you will have to do a review of the different tenses to determine which tense is the one you want.  The first implies the crowd cheered as a result of the action taken by the referee.  The latter (ignoring the error of  'were' which should be 'was') means the crowd was cheering already irrespective of the action taken by the referee.

Comment: The progressive _was cheering_ means that the cheer started before the whistle sounded and continued through the whistle (perhaps drowning out the whistle). The simple past _cheered_, on the other hand, means that the whistle sounded **before** the cheer started. As you say, there's no reason to use a progressive with _blow_ in either case, since the whistle is a punctual event, while the cheer is durative.